# ServiceStack implement magic token in deserializer

Tags: serialization, servicestack

I want to implement a magic token for my ServiceStack-based API. Whenever any value matches this special token, I'd like to signal special actions in my application. The ideal place for this assignment to occur would be *after* SS had processed the wire format (JSV, JSON, SOAP, etc.) and *before* it mapped the value onto the a .NET type. At the moment, I'm wondering about the best way to start on something like this. Is it something I could wire up in `Configure()`? Is it something I'll have to override and inject? Any assistance or direction in this matter would be appreciated, ASAP.

Comment: "Whenever any value matches this special token" - what exactly do you mean by "value"? Any property value in any DTO?

Comment: Yes. Regardless of type or DTO or any other restriction, I want to allow this magic value as an input and trigger a behavior based on its presence. This is why it needs to be intercepted before SS attempts to map to a type; I want fields that are int/bool/whatever on DTO to be able to have this magic string value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this as a ServiceStack implementation question, but rather a matter of how you define your DTOs.  Given this requirement, as I understand it, I'd go with something like this:

```
 interface IOverridableDTO
 {
    Object overrideValue(Object value);
 }

 class BaseOverridableDTO : IOverridableDTO
 {
    bool doOverride {get(){return(//results of magic token check)};}

    public Object overrideValue(Object value)
    { if {doOverride} 
           return(null);  // or whatever the override needs to be
       return(value);
    }
 }

 class MyDTO : BaseOverridableDTO
 {
    // override the overrideValue() method, if necessary

    private int myDTOProperty;
    public int? MyDTOProperty {
         get() {return overrideValue((Object)myDTOProperty)}; 
         set(int value) {myDTOProperty = value;}
    }
 }

 // use as follows:
 void DoSomethingWithAnOverridableDTO(BaseOverridableDTO dtoObject)
 { ... }
```